# HTML5 canvas drawing board - touch support

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am using this simple script to enable users to enter their signatures. Unfortunately, this does not work on mobile devices.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var container = document.getElementById('container');
var container_style = getComputedStyle(container);
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 300;

var mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
}, false);

ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
ctx.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";

function getSize(size){ctx.lineWidth = size;}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
}, false);

var onPaint = function() {
    ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    ctx.stroke();
};
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

**Is there an easy way to add touch support to this script?**

Comment: Use pointer events: `pointerdown`, `pointerup`, and `pointermove`.

Comment: When I replace the mouse event by pointer events it is not working correctly on mobile devices. Are there any other changes that need to be done here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make these changes to your code:

1. Use pointer events (instead of mouse events): `pointerdown`, `pointerup`, and `pointermove`. Pointer events work for both mouse and touch interactions.
2. Add `touch-action: none` to your canvas CSS. This prevents the dragging of your finger from triggering the device's panning action (which stops your drawing).
3. Set your "mouse" coordinates upon `pointerdown`. This will stop previous lines from being connected to new ones.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var container = document.getElementById('container');
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 300;

var mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};

canvas.addEventListener('pointermove', function(e) {
  mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
}, false);

ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
ctx.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';

canvas.addEventListener('pointerdown', function(e) {
  mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
  canvas.addEventListener('pointermove', onPaint, false);
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener('pointerup', function() {
  canvas.removeEventListener('pointermove', onPaint, false);
}, false);

var onPaint = function() {
  ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
  ctx.stroke();
};
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  touch-action: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```